# How do I open port 22 in OS X 10.6.7

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to open port 22 on osx so I can connect to localhost using ssh.  This is my current situation:

```
ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

I have generated a key and tossed it into my authorized_keys file like so:

```
sh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

A "Network Utility" port scan confirms that 22 (and surprisingly 23) are closed.

Context: I am working on getting Hadoop set up locally.  In my configuration, I am running services on localhost:####s and need to open communications to them via ssh.

How can I open 22?  or could I be up against another issue (improperly generated key perhaps?)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I think your port is probably open, but you don't have anything that listens on it.

> The Apple Mac OS X operating system has SSH installed by default but
>   the SSH daemon is not enabled. This means you can’t login remotely or
>   do remote copies until you enable it.
>
> To enable it, go to ‘System Preferences’. Under ‘Internet & Networking’ there is a ‘Sharing’ icon. Run that. In the list
>   that appears, check the ‘Remote Login’ option. In OS X Yosemite and up, there is no longer an 'Internet & Networking' menu; it was moved to Accounts. The Sharing menu now has its own icon on the main System Preferences menu. (thx @AstroCB)
>
> This starts the SSH daemon immediately and you can remotely login
>   using your username. The ‘Sharing’ window shows at the bottom the name
>   and IP address to use. You can also find this out using ‘whoami’ and
>   ‘ifconfig’ from the Terminal application.

These instructions are copied from [Enable SSH in Mac OS X](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/mac-ssh.html), but I wanted to make sure they won't go away and to provide quick access.

Comment: I can't understand what you have done. Exact where sharing icon is available. please, help me.

Comment: It's under System Preferences, available under the Apple menu at the top.

Comment: Also make sure you have "Allow Access For all Users" if you are not the admin.

Comment: FYI: In OS X Yosemite and up, there is no longer an 'Internet & Networking' menu; it was moved to Accounts. The Sharing menu now has its own icon on the main System Preferences menu.

Answer (score 36):

I'm using OSX 10.11.6 and [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2016/08/16/enable-ssh-mac-command-line/%20How%20to%20Enable%20SSH%20on%20a%20Mac%20from%20the%20Command%20Line) works for me.

[image]

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 16):

There are 3 solutions available for these.

1) Enable  remote login using below command
 - **sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on**

2) In Mac, go to **System Preference -> Sharing -> enable Remote Login 
that's it. 100% working solution**

3) **Final and most important solution is** - Check your private area network connection . Sometime remote login isn't allow inside the local area network.

**Kindly try to connect your machine using personal network like mobile network, Hotspot etc.**

Answer (score 7):

If you try to enable remote login from a terminal window, you may get a "full disk permission issue". Alternatively, You can enable it from **Apple Icon -> System Preferences -> Sharing**

I am using **Mac-bigSur** and this is how I enable it on my machine

[image]

You can allow access to specific users also.

Answer (score 4):

As per macOS 10.14.5, below are the details:

Go to

> system preferences > sharing > remote login.

Comment: This is easiest way!Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem;  Then I did the following and the issue was resolved:
Refer [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ssh-connection-refused.1516735/):

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist  
    (Supply your password when it is requested)   
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist  
ssh -v localhost  
sudo launchctl list | grep "sshd"  
    46427   -   com.openssh.sshd
```

Comment: I followed this process and got '34720 0 com.openssh.sshd.long_string_of_digits_and_numbers', but 'ssh username@IP_address' still gives me 'ssh: connect to host IP_address port 22: Connection refused'