# how to run jenkins as super user?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, root, sudoers

I am Mahesh.
I installed jenkins in my linux machine,IT works well as a normal user, When i try to run one script in super user [root] mode,It is not working properly,Even i disable the password in sudoers file it is not working and also It not giving any error It just running the script in normal user instead of root ?? what i do? how i can resolve this problem ??

I just add like this in shell script coloumn in jenkins...

**sudo su**   //*comment-->I disable the password so no password required ,I tested in the terminal and         am able to enter into root without password with this*

**sh something.sh**

Comment: How did you install Jenkins? Which version? Which Linux distribution are you using? Which version? What does your /etc/sudoers file look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a script as root in Jenkins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880070/how-to-run-a-script-as-root-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 5):

I would advise against running Jenkins (or any application server) as the root user.

Instead of battling the sudo command, why not install the [Jenkins ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) and configure the jenkins user to perform an ssh login to the root account?

Comment: this could be a good solution. could you please provide a quick walkthrough? as i've downloaded the plugin, but cannot get it to login to localhost. i've searched and read my ass off :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313929/how-do-i-open-port-22-in-osx-10-6-7 f.e. 
yet i still cannot get it work.

Comment: Yes, i am. Thanks for coming back to this, i've decided to use the standalone Jenkins app someone made. This seems more logical, then i also not have to have it run allways, as i'm not allways developing anyway :)