# tmux session created in jenkins execute shell, is gone after jenkins build finished

Tags: shell, jenkins, tmux

I'm trying to create some tmux sessions in jenkins execute shell step, and put some long running script into those tmux session. I have a tmux `ls` check in execute shell, and I can see those tmux session was created properly. But after jenkins build finished, those tmux session are gone.

Is there any way I can keep those tmux session after jenkins build run?

Is that something related to jenkins execute shell from `$ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1362639696643230840.sh`  ?

Thanks for any kind of hint!

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating the tmux sessions within the execute step. Try adding them to a script and call the script in the jenkins execute step.

Comment: I had a similar issue, Jenkins was not running as  sudoer. By calling the script with Jenkins as a sudoer, these  sessions  will be sustained.  Did  you even try calling a script ?. I used tip  from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880070/how-to-run-a-script-as-root-in-jenkins/11880102