# Running a command as root in JenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a command which requires root in JenkinsFile.But when i run it on my localhost it gives error that "sudo not found".The JenkinsFile is in the source code.

```
stage('Install packages') {
  sh("docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/app -w /app node yarn install")
  sh("sudo chown -R jenkins: ./node_modules")
}
```

I have already tried this. [How to run a script as root in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880070/how-to-run-a-script-as-root-in-jenkins)  The temp sh script is created on each build.
And the error is

`/var/jenkins_home/workspace/boilerplate_master-2ESKZDF4PBIXGKODFFKIVAND5RN5VWF6QLEGRZ44LZGESCULVC4Q@tmp/durable-14d87eaa/script.sh: line 1: sudo: not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing "sudo not found" since **sudo** is not installed on your docker image. 
Check the default user's ID. 
**i.e.** For Maven, it is the root user (ID: 0).

The user may be mapped to ID, and not name. 
**i.e.** The user ID on host is 1000, which corresponds to the user node in the image.

```
sh “chown -R 1000 /mydir”  /* Replace 1000 with actual user ID> */
```

The above command will solve your issue if the user IDs match, or else it will set an unknown owner to your files.

Please try the following Jenkins script I wrote based on the Docker image you provided.

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages{
    stage('test'){
        steps{
            script{
                    def image = docker.image('mhart/alpine-node:8.11.3')
                    image.pull()
                    image.inside() {
                        sh 'id'
                        sh 'ls -lrt'
                        sh 'node yarn install'
                    }
              }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the point if writing a JenkinsFile if it doesnt run everywhere?
I will have to map user ID to hostID for every system.Is there any workaround?

Comment: We use extensively docker in our Jenkins. Only workaround I found was either use docker images that runs with root user( not highly recommended by docker community) or use those images which has a matching user that of host.

Comment: It returned invalid spec `1001` when i did `sh “chown -R 1000 /mydir”`.

Comment: Which docker image are you using? What’s the user ID of your Jenkins user ?

Comment: The docker image is `mhart/alpine-node:8.11.3` and the userID of the jenkins user is 1001.

Comment: To some extent it did solve the problem but now new problem has creeped saying `node yarn build` not found.
I think when i use it on my system i have to use `sudo yarn build` to build reactApp thats why it isnt working

Answer (score 0):

try to run such commands as 'jenkins' user instead:

```
stage('Install packages') {
  sh("docker run --user='jenkins' --rm -v `pwd`:/app -w /app node yarn install")
}
```