# Sudo apt-get install commands with Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a jenkins server open and I'm attempting to sudo install:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Because I am using a pipeline that runs a python script, whereby this script would return the following error:

> builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Online articles have suggested to sudo install the package above. However, I would need root-privileges to do so.

I have installed the `ssh-server` plugin within jenkins and `jenkins-cli.jar`, is there a way to install the package with any of these two options, or an easier alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880070/how-to-run-a-script-as-root-in-jenkins

Comment: Another approach is to use temporary build slaves running Docker where the slave gets full privileges to install software as required.

Comment: @tripleee I have checked that article however I did not build our jenkins server. Not sure about docker, I have little experience with it.

Comment: Then probably talk to your Jenkins admin about this requirement, as there is probably no way you can solve it without their cooperation.

Comment: @tripleee Our admin is an introvert that never communicates with any one ... One difficult situation to another :)