# Jenkins identity file not accessible

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, permissions, devops, ssh-keys

I am new to Jenkins and DevOps in general. I am trying to learn to deploy war files onto Tomcat 9.xx running on an amazon EC2 instance. Tomcat is accessible via the browser

I have the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
         string(name: 'tomcat_dev', defaultValue: 'VALID_IP_HIDDEN', description: 'Staging Server')
    }

    triggers {
         pollSCM('* * * * *')
     }

stages{
        stage('Build'){
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    echo 'Now Archiving...'
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war'
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Deployments'){
            parallel{
                stage ('Deploy to Staging'){
                    steps {
                        sh "scp -i /home/user/.ssh/tomcatdeployment.pem **/target/*.war ec2-user@${params.tomcat_dev}:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.83/webapps"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to connect to my ec2 instance using the above identity file but when I run my Jenkins Pipeliine, I keep getting this error:

**scp -i /home/user/.ssh/tomcatdeployment.pem webapp/target/webapp.war ec2-user@IP_VALUE_HIDDEN:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.83/webapps
Warning: Identity file /home/user/.ssh/tomcatdeployment.pem not accessible: Permission denied.
Host key verification failed.**

I have tried to add Jenkins to the root users list and enabled it to use sudo without a password following - [How to run a script as root in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880070/how-to-run-a-script-as-root-in-jenkins)

But I still encounter the same error. Can anyone help or provide some guidance?

Comment: Seems like your jenkins user does not have access to this file, you can try to copy your identity file to home of jenkins user and make jenkins user the owner of that file.

Comment: this did not work

Comment: the issue was actually related to this post - https://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error

Answer (score 0):

You may please set the right credentials to authenticate with the Jenkins server.
Host Key Verification Issue: `ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/tomcatdeployment.pem ec2-user@IP_VALUE_HIDDEN`

Comment: I dont understad where you would like me to use the ssh command. my file is using an scp command. Can you please clarify.