# Gitolite and Firewall

Tags: gitolite

So, I just enabled Firewall on my MacOSX Lion machine which runs the `gitolite` server and `git` can no longer connect to `remote` from other machines in the same home network.

More Info: I've kept the `ssh` standard port open the server machine.

I also found this http://www.42.mach7x.com/2011/07/12/using-gitolite-in-a-non-standard-ssh-port/. But it does not apply to me as I have the standard port open.

What could I be missing?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313929/how-do-i-open-port-22-in-osx-10-6-7 doesn't help?

Comment: Or https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3679427?start=0&tstart=0, to eliminate all the other causes.

Comment: Otherwise... http://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x ;)

Comment: Thanks for those links, they my problem seems unrelated. Perhaps this is a question for serverfault.